# Prove image of continuous periodic function is a closed and bounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, compactness

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function with period $C$.  Prove that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is a closed and bounded interval.

My proof below.  Can you verify or critique?

Since $f$ is periodic, it suffices to consider the image of $[0, C]$ under $f$.  A closed and bounded interval on the real line is compact, and the image of a compact interval under a continuous function is a compact interval, and hence closed and bounded. QED.

---

### Update: Simpler Proof

A more elementary proof: By the Extreme Value Theorem, $f$ takes on a max $a$ and min $b$ in $[0,C]$.  $f$ takes on no values outside $[a, b]$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, $f$ takes on all values inside $[a,b]$.  Thus, the image of $f$ is $[a,b]$.

Comment: Looks good.....

Comment: This is OK when you take it for granted that for any $x\in \Bbb R$ there exists $n\in\Bbb Z$ with $x+nC\in [0,C]$ and that $f(x)=f(x+nC)$ for all $x\in \Bbb R, n\in \Bbb Z.$ These are true, of course, and we don't expect to see them proved every time you need them.